# Unable to create nuxt-app using npm command line

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, npx, create-nuxt-app

Command:

```
npx create-nuxt-app project-name
```

Error:

```
sh: create-nuxt-app: command not found
```

I'm trying to resolve the issue by running the following command:

```
npm i -g create-nuxt-app
```

But it gets stuck at the following step:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
(##################) ⠋ reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/create-nuxt-app/node_modules/lodash Completed in 461ms
```

Comment: Issue was resolved. I just needed to wait bit longer.

Comment: Fore reference: it took about 6-7 minutes for create-nuxt-app to prepare and start the actual setup.

Answer (score 2):

This command actually resolved the issue.

```
npm i -g create-nuxt-app
```

Issue was resolved. I just needed to wait bit longer